# Rename files asynchronously in Node.js if destination files don't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs, fs-extra

I am trying to rename files asynchronously in Node.js only if destination files *don't exist*.

I made a quick test like follows:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const files = [ 'file1', 'file2', 'file3' ]
const new_name = 'new-name' // same destination name for all
```

> [fs.exists()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) - DEPRECATED

```
for (let file of files)

  fs.exists(new_name, (exists) => {
    if (!exists) fs.rename(file, new_name, (err) => {})
   })
```

> [fs.access()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) - RECOMMENDED

```
for (let file of files)

  fs.access(new_name, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
    if (err) fs.rename(file, new_name, (err) => {})
  })
```

> [fs.move()](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/move.md) - from [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)

```
const fs_extra = require('fs-extra')

for (let file of files) 

  fs_extra.move(file, new_name, { overwrite: false }, (err) => {})
```

---

**Each time all 3 files were overwriten and renamed to one file.**

---

I believe this is happens because all `exists` checks fire sooner than any `rename` happens.

I know how to accomplish this task synchronously, but want to be sure that there is no proper async way to do so.

Comment: Have you considered using the async-await for this?

Comment: Use async module in nodejs and use `async.waterfall` .Check this link to see various options in async module. https://medium.com/velotio-perspectives/understanding-node-js-async-flows-parallel-serial-waterfall-and-queues-6f9c4badbc17

Comment: @cr05s19xx nope. To my regret I am lack of knowledge how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create `Promise` which `resolve`'s when file is renamed

```
fs.rename(file, new_name, (err) => {
    resolve(); <------
});
```

or when renaming is skipped

```
fs.access(new_name, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return fs.rename(file, new_name, (err) => {
            resolve();
        });
    }
    resolve(); <------
});
```

Full code

```
(async () => {
    for (let file of files) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            fs.access(new_name, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    return fs.rename(file, new_name, (err) => {
                        resolve();
                    });
                }
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
})();
```

and if you don't want to mix `async`/`await` with `Promise`

```
(async () => {
    function rename(file, new_name) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            fs.access(new_name, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    return fs.rename(file, new_name, (err) => {
                        resolve();
                    });
                }
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }

    for (let file of files) {
        await rename(file, new_name);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Works wonderfully. Thanks for the answer. Do you know how accomplish this with async.waterfall?

Answer (score 2):

@ponury-kostek solution works brilliantly and marked as accepted answer.

I ended up with the following code since it's a bit shorter:

```
async function rename_files() {

  for (let file of files)                
      await fs.move(file, new_name)
}
```

```
rename_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of wrapping fs library in promises.
- I like to import the promise implementation of the fs library.
- Then call the fs methods with *await*.

.

```
import {promises as fs_promises} from 'fs'; // The promise implmentation of fs library.

async function renameFile() {
    const fileFullPath = '1234.txt';
    const newFileFullPath = '5678.txt';

    await fs_promises.rename(fileFullPath, newFileFullPath, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("\nFile Renamed\n");
        }
    });
}

await renameFile(); // Call the async method.
```